# Should I deploy api-gateway on GKE engine?

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, spring-cloud

I am working on a demo project , which has 5 microservices - discovery server , api-gateway , user-order-detail , order  and user service.

I will expose the order and user service internally

I will expose the user-order-detail service externally which will call the other two services using a rest endpoint.

1) Should I deploy discovery server and api gateway on kubernetes engine and if not how will the routing be handled ?

If I do not deploy the api-gateway , how will this rest call take place ?

[image]

2) Also as there is a application.properties file in every spring-cloud project. Does docker image replace the application.properties file ?

3) I am using docker and kubernetes for the first time.Can someone explain what should be my next step after creating the docker images for my services ? (just the steps , I will figure out how to complete those steps)

**UPDATE:**

**Services that are up:**

user-order-detail  LoadBalancer
kubernetes         ClusterIP
order-management   LoadBalancer
user-management    LoadBalancer

user-order-detail hits an endpoint to retrieve all users.
***I am getting this error :No matches for the virtual host name :user-management***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find the answers below:-

1) Yes, you can deploy discovery service and api-gateway on kubernetes engine and please go through this document in regards which type of service you will expose.

> Services:- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

2) You can copy the application.properties file while building the image or if you want to override at the run time. Please create a configMap in Kubernetes and inject into the Kubernetes pod by volume. Please follow below links on ConfigMap.

> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume
>
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume

3) Steps to do after creating images:-

1. Push the image to registry
2. Deploy the pod on kubernetes
3. Create a service to expose the pod

Comment: Thanks for the response , but kubernetes handles routing and service discovery internally . What if I want to use that ? I was trying to understand the concept through this article https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-microservices-spring-cloud-vs-kubernetes.

Comment: When you create a service type `ClusterIP`, you can access that service within the cluster by using the service name.

Comment: so there is no need to change the code I have written  for the rest call ?

Comment: No, because if service is created as ClusterIP, you can access it in any other pod as well

Comment: I have reached this step but getting this error: No matches for the virtual host name :user-management

Comment: Can you please list down all the services here by running command:- `kubectl get svc`

Comment: I have mentioned all the services in my question above.

Comment: As you mentioned, LoadBalancer type, use have to use IP or DNS name, I would suggest use `ClusterIP` type service

Answer (score 0):

Beside an API Gateway, you can also use an Ingress for exposing your services. Ingress is more likely a native solution at kubernetes because it uses kubernetes syntax for configuring, means you don't need much refactoring when you want to change the gateway (ingress). you can compare ingresses available here :

https://kubedex.com/ingress/

If you still want an API Gateway, I recommend to use this as this use envoy and it 's built natively for kubernetes

https://www.getambassador.io/